# Is there a way to make a channel emote-only in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm looking for a way to limit one text-channel to just using emotes only. So in case the message contains text, it get deleted by the bot instantly.

Example of the code logic:

```
if (message.isEmoteOnly()) {
  console.log('Emote-only message detected');
} else {
  message.delete();
  message.channel.send('Your message has been deleted! This channel is in emote-only mode.');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple, more elegant, and less exploitative way of checking if text is in the format of an emoji is with a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

```js
/:[^:\s]+:|<:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>|<a:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>/g
```

To see it in action and understand what each token does, check it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/NYIQAt/2). I highly suggest doing so before reading the explanation below.

It may seem a little confusing at first, so breaking this down as to why it works...

- **`:[^:\s]+:`**
  The format of a "normal" emoji is **`:name:`**. The surrounding `:` match the colons while `[^:\s]+` matches the characters in between. `:` (that would signify the end of the template) and line breaks (that would count as the character in between which would not form an emoji) are excluded.
- **`<:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>`**
  The format of a custom emoji is **`<:name:id>`**. The surrounding `<:` and `>` match the beginning and end of the template. `[^:\s]+` matches the name. The colon between the name and ID is matched literally. `[0-9]+` matches the numbers inside. *I'm not using `\d` for digits because other Unicode characters classified as such can be matched.*
- **`<a:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>`**
  The format of an animated emoji is **`<a:name:id>`**. The `<` and `>` match the beginning and end of the template. `a:` matches itself literally. `[^:\s]+` matches the name. `:` is matched in between the name and the ID literally. `[0-9]+` matches the ID.

Now, implementing this into your code...

```js
// Replace all emojis to leave just the text, if any.
const text = message.content.replace(/:[^:\s]+:|<:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>|<a:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>/g, '');

// Check if 'text' is not blank to see if there are characters which are not used in emojis.
if (text) {
  message.delete()
    .catch(console.error);
}
```

If you'd like to only allow *one* emoji in a message, you can define the start and end of the string, and remove the global modifier.

```js
/^(:[^:\s]+:|<:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>|<a:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>)$/
```

This will make sure that this is the only content within the message.

**Edit:**

To allow spaces between emojis, you can simply replace them in `text` after removing the emojis. In the example below, `\s` is also including line breaks (replace it with a space if this isn't the desired result).

```js
const text = message.content.replace(/:[^:\s]+:|<:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>|<a:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Test it out below.

```js
const str = ':smile: <a:parrot:1234> <:parrot:1234>';

const text = str.replace(/:[^:\s]+:|<:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>|<a:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '');

if (text) console.log('Not allowed.');
else console.log('Allowed.');
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering, i tested the Regular Expression on regex101.com and it seems to be working as expected, however it doesn't work with the `replace()`` function: https://jsfiddle.net/ovs54m8e/

Comment: If `text` is truthy, the message is *not* an emoji (because text other than what's in the emojis is present). Your example has it the other way.

Comment: Thanks i get it now, but the `<:a:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>` part doesn't work because Discord emotes are in format of `<a:name:id>`, not `<:a:name:id>`... So i fixed the issue by changing ``<:a:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>`` to ``<a:[^:\s]+:[0-9]+>``...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the answer for future readers.

Comment: Also there is another issue with the first regex, it doesn't work if there is space between emotes. For example `<:emote:189855563893571595><:emote:18985556389571595>`, works but ``<:emote:189855563893571595> <:emote:18985556389571595>`` doesn't work! Is there any way to fix it? i'm not familiar with Regular expressions. https://jsfiddle.net/ovs54m8e/3/

Comment: Edited the answer to accommodate for whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if the clean message content starts with `:` and ends with `:`, or `<:` and `>` for custom emotes. You can do so by using

```js
message.content.startsWith(':') && message.content.endsWith(':')
```

or

```js
/* 'a' are animated emotes */

(message.content.startsWith('<a:') || message.content.startsWith('<:')) && message.content.endsWith('>')
```

Users can exploit this however by doing `:emote: loltext :emote:`. If you want to avoid this, I advise filtering out emotes, and checking if strings still exist.

```js
// THIS IS A VERY SLOPPY WAY OF DOING THIS!!!!!!! DONT USE THIS FOR PRODUCTION
let split = message.content.split(' ');
for (let i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
  if (!(split[i].startsWith(':') && split[i].endsWith(':')) && !((split[i].startsWith('<a:') || split[i].startsWith('<:')) && split[i].endsWith('>'))) {
    console.log(`has text: ${split[i]}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: I think checking if the message content starts and ends with `:` can be exploited by the users. but i just tested your second code example and it works perfectly. I'm still not sure if `<a:` works for animated emotes because i don't have a nitro but i'll tell one of my friends who has nitro to test it for me. Thank you!

Comment: Wait nevermind actually the second example can be exploited too if the user types ``<:test>``. But thanks anyway, haven't looked into your third code example yet.

Comment: @ExillustX the third example checks for non-emote words, however it's very sloppy when it comes to how it chceks >~< I advise you change it up so it matches your coding style! It basically loops through every word and checks if the word starts and ends with emote wrappers.